# "Function uses '80408' bytes of stack: exceeds analyze:stacksize '16384'. Consider moving some data to heap" C++ error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, stack-overflow

I am trying to generate data and place them into separate files
This is a part of the code which gives me a stacksize error. I have tried adjusting the compiler to change the stacksize and suppress the warning message but it did not work.
When I run the code it does not create the output files and keeps on running without giving an output.
How can I fix this PLEASE?

This is my code:

```
double generateWindData(double windData[4])
{
int avgWindSpeed = windData[0];
int gust = windData[1];
int simulationDuration = windData[2];
int stepSize = windData[3];
int stepCounter = simulationDuration / stepSize + 1;

ofstream windFile;
windFile.open("WindSpeedData.txt", ios::out);
if (windFile.fail())
{
    cerr << "WindSpeedData.txt could not be opened." << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

int upperLimit = avgWindSpeed + gust;
int lowerLimit = avgWindSpeed - gust;
int randomWindSpeeds = rand() % ((upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) + lowerLimit);

double simulatedSpeeds[10000];
int* initialSpeeds = new int[stepCounter];
int* times = new int[stepCounter];
int time = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stepCounter; i++)
{
    initialSpeeds[i] = randomWindSpeeds;
    simulatedSpeeds[i] = initialSpeeds[i];
    times[i] = time;
    windFile << times[i] << ' ' << initialSpeeds[i] << endl;
    time += stepSize;
}

ofstream finalFile;
finalFile.open("WindSimulation.txt", ios::out);
if (finalFile.fail())
{
    cerr << "WindSimulation.txt could not be opened." << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < stepCounter; i++) {
    finalFile << times[i] << ' ' << simulatedSpeeds[i] << ' '; 
    if (simulatedSpeeds[i] != initialSpeeds[i]) 
    {
        finalFile << '1' << endl; //this outputs 1 to WindSimulation.txt if storm takes place
    }
    else {
        finalFile << endl;
    }
}
finalFile.close();
```

}

Comment: `simulatedSpeeds[i] != initialSpeeds[i]` can't ever be true. All your values are the same; they are `randomWindSpeeds`.

Comment: You have a memory leak with `int* initialSpeeds = new int[stepCounter];` and `int* times = new int[stepCounter];`. Please consider using `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace `simulatedSpeeds` with a dynamically allocated array, e.g. `std::vector`, so it would look like this: `std::vector<double> simulatedSpeeds;` (you can also use its `reserve` method) and then inside the loop the `simulatedSpeeds[i] = initialSpeeds[i];` should be replaced with `simulatedSpeeds.push_back(initialSpeeds[i]);`